# I am getting 404 error

Tags: java, servlets

I am using java servlet to simply get the form values and display it. I have done all the changes posted by others for this problem. But still I am getting this error.

This my servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/UpdateDetails")
    public class updateDetails extends HttpServlet 
    {    
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
       {
          <br/>
          String name=request.getParameter("appName");<br/>
          System.out.println(name);

          PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

          // build HTML code
          String htmlRespone = "<html>";
          htmlRespone += "<h2>Application: " + name + "<br/>";
          htmlRespone += "</html>";

          // return response
          writer.println(htmlRespone);
       }
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="edit" action="UpdateDetails">
```

Comment: 404 means resource-not-found, so I would bet your servlet is not being called at all.  You need to verify that your servlet has been mapped to a URL in your web.xml file for your web application.

Comment: Try with `action="/nameOfYourWebApplication/UpdateDetails"`.

Comment: @ewh We need not specify url in web.xml if we are using annotation right?

Comment: @Pshemo I tried.It is of new use.Still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Are you using any IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes,I am using Eclipse IDE.I tried I am getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try running your servlet from URL `http://yourServer/yourWebApp/UpdateDetails`? (right-click on your `updateDetails.java` code -> run as -> server). Can you post URL which was used to run it?

Comment: did you try `action="/UpdateDetails"`.What IDE are you using?

Comment: @Pshemo   I am getting the following error,[link] (HTTP Status 404 - /Dashboard_new/servlet/com.monitoring.servlets.updateDetails)

Comment: @Pshemo        (http://localhost:4620/Dashboard_new/updatestatus.html). When I give the form values and press submit.The form values are getting appended to the url,But I am getting http Status: 404 /Dashboard_new/Updatedetails is not available

Comment: @Anusha Sajeendran. If you are using eclipse IDE and if you have configured tomcat in your eclispe IDE i would recommend you to go through this link. I hope this might solve your problem. http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html . Check out the 7 point in the link "Copy the ROOT (Default) Web App into Eclipse." . And one more thing i noticed in your servlet is the contetType is not set. Try setting response.setContentType("text/html")

Comment: I am not JEE expert so I don't know why you are using `4620` port. But I suspect that if your `<form..>` will be opened with default port (`80`) then it will also try to connect with `localhost:80/Dashboard_new/updatestatus.html`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. My code is working after mapping url in web.xml.